# ¿Borrar un registro en angular 5 pasando el user_id?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, angular4

quiero borrar un registro pasandole el user id utilizando httpclient mi api desde postman le paso el 1 como parametro y me borra el registro pero en angular nose este es mi codigo

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    templateUrl: './main.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent {

    archivo: Array<any>;

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
        this.conseguir();
        console.log(this.archivo);
    }

    conseguir() {
        const url = 'http://localhost/api/public/archivo';

        this._http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
            this.archivo = data;
        }, error => {
            console.log('error');
        })
    }

    borrar(archivo) {
        const urls = `http://localhost/api/public/delete/${archivo.user_id}`;

        this._http.delete(urls).subscribe(data => {
            console.log('se ha borrado correctamente');
        }, error => {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }
}
```

en mi html tengo la el evento click

```
<main>

<div *ngFor="let datos of archivo" class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
 <img class="card-img-top" [src]="'/assets/img/'+ datos.imagen" alt="Card 
 image cap">
 <div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">{{datos.titulo}}</h5>
<h5 class="card-title">{{datos.user_id}}</h5>
<p class="card-text">{{datos.descripcion}}</p>

<i (click)="borrar(???????)" class="material-icons">delete</i>

 </div>
 </div>
```

mi tablas de la base de datos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la función conseguir me devuelve todos los datos de la tabla y me lo almacena en la variable archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu **HTML**, debería quedarte algo como esto:

```
<div *ngFor="let datos of archivo" class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" [src]="'/assets/img/'+ datos.imagen" alt="Card 
   image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{datos.titulo}}</h5>
    <h5 class="card-title">{{datos.user_id}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{datos.descripcion}}</p>

    <i (click)="borrar(datos)" class="material-icons">delete</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y tu función borrar, refactorizandola un poco para que este mejor:

```
borrar(archivoParaBorrar) {
        const url = `http://localhost/api/public/delete/${archivoParaBorrar.user_id}`;

       this._http.delete(url).subscribe(data => {
          console.log('se ha borrado correctamente');
          let index = archivo.indexOf(archivoParaBorrar, 0);
          if (index > -1) {
            archivo.splice(index, 1); // Tu array de archivos
         }
       }, error => {
        console.log('error');
      });           
}
```

Como puedes ver, si la petición resulta exitosa remueve el objeto de tu Array.

---

Hablando un poco de buenas practicas:

> Deberías definir a un servicio para realizar las peticiones http, sea el tipo que sea.

Comment: funcionaaa vale muchas gracias pero ahora cunado lo borro se borra de la base de datos pero en la pagina no se me actualiza el borrado como seria eso  se me quedan los datos del html en la vista???

Comment: Si, claramente, tu BD y tu vista son cosas diferentes. Una petición http de delete, va a borrar lo que se encuentre en tu servidor. Utiliza el id que tienes en la función de borrar y remover el objeto de tu array. Ahí modifique la respuesta.

Comment: no entiendo si me lo puedes explicar mejor te lo agradeceria porque llevo ya varios dias con esto y no me entero

Comment: Mira el código de `borrar()`, de mi respuesta y dime que no entiendes.

Comment: a vale gracias....

Comment: se podria hacer de otra manera me resulta complejo de entender

Comment: no se podria hacer con map o alguna otra forma porque si tengo mas proyectos no entiendo indexof

Comment: Si Javier, eso queda a tu elección, es una decisión de diseño. Te recomiendo leas un poco más sobre TypeScript para que puedas tener un mejor criterio, [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_string_indexof.htm) esta la explicación de `indexOf`, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios problemas en el código:

Tu clase tiene un atributo `archivo`, pero lo declaras como un array. ¿Debería ser `archivos`? ¿Debería ser un único objeto?

Tu método `borrar(archivo) {...}` espera un parámetro, pero no le estás pasando ninguno al clickar sobre el elemento. ¿Te sobra el parámetro y te quieres referir al atributo o se te ha olvidado pasarlo como índice para saber qué archivo de tu array quieres borrar?

Comment: como se declaraia de otra forma no entiendo, y el parametro que le tengo que pasar nose ???? ayudame estoy empezando con esto y no se mucho

Comment: Como dice Pablo, al borrar tenes que pasarle lo que quieras borrar, cuando se dispara el evento click.   `(click)="borrar( el-archivo-aquí )"` Como no podemos ver tu html, no se si tienes ese archivo en algún lugar en la vista.

Comment: ¿Qué recibes del servidor? Mueve la línea console.log(this.archivo); a la subscripción del .get(....) o siempre tendrás undefined y no lo sabrás

Comment: necesito pasarle un parametro al (click)="borrar()" en teoria seria el user _id pero como le paso eso lo tengo dentro de bucle for

Comment: Añade a tu pregunta el código con el bucle